# How to init a struct that includes a slice for Google auto generated lib

Tags: go, struct, google-analytics-api, object-slicing

I'm trying to make a Google Analytics Go library based off the auto generated package generated [here](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/analyticsreporting/v4#ReportRequest)

I have authenticated, got account summaries etc. so all is well until I try to construct a reporting request.

I am trying to init a struct ReportRequest that has the following:

```
type ReportRequest struct {

    DateRanges []*DateRange `json:"dateRanges,omitempty"`

    ...etc
}
```

How can I made a function that wraps this struct so I can pass in the values?  Consulting the [DateRange struct](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/analyticsreporting/v4#DateRange)
 it seems simple enough, but I get messages about not passing in a slice pointer to DateRange which I can't figure out how to construct.

I have tried this:

```
func makeRequest(
    start, end string) *ga.GetReportsRequest {

    daterangep := &ga.DateRange{StartDate: start, EndDate: end}

    requests := ga.ReportRequest{}
    requests.DateRanges = daterangep
```

But get a compiler error:

```
cannot use daterangep (type *analyticsreporting.DateRange) as type []*analyticsreporting.DateRange in assignment
```

Is it possible to send in JSON?  I see some MarshalJSON functions that I don't know if I can use,and the json declaration in the object but I'd prefer to be able to use Go objects.

Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `&[]*analyticsreporting.DateRange{{StartDate: start, EndDate: end}}`. And replace `analyticsreporting` with `ga` if you renamed the import.

Comment: ... for more details see [link](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Comment: Thanks!  It was `daterangep := []*ga.DateRange{{StartDate: start, EndDate: end}}`  not including the `&`  but compiler happy now - please do add ytour answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Looks like my Q got voted down because this was VERY basic, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize a slice you can use a [literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

```
daterangep := []*ga.DateRange{{StartDate: start, EndDate: end}}
```

You can use [`make`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels):

```
daterangep := make([]*ga.DateRange, 1)
daterangep[0] = &ga.DateRange{StartDate: start, EndDate: end}
```

Or you can declare it and then use [`append`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices):

```
var daterangep []*ga.DateRange
daterangep = append(daterangep, &ga.DateRange{StartDate: start, EndDate: end})
```